# "New" item does not exist in list

Tags: custom-list

In my Employee list, I added **4 hours ago** a new item. I guess it created the item properly, since a workflow ran on it:

[image]

The link works perfectly well and I was able to update the item.
However, when I search the item, it is nowhere to be found:

[image: Search on item dos not send result]

*(Translation : Your search did not yield any result)*

I know my search works:

[image: Search on another item works]

My list view is ID sorted, so this is my last entries:

[image: Employees Last ID]

And as you can see, I am far from the 5000 items threshold limit.

Question : Someone can guide me/explain me what is wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The search works only if an item has been crawled. You should check with your admin to see how often is the search crawler set to work.

Comment: The question remains: Not only I can not search the item, but it does not appear in the list at all.

Comment: Hm, if you were able to update the item than it must have been created... You should check if there are any filters in your view that prevent the new item to be shown.

Comment: is this a list item or it's a document? did you check that the list has no versioning enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my French. If someone wants to edit the answer to add an English picture, please feel free. I would like to thanks Damjan who with his answer, laid a trail of pebbles for me to find the solution (Hansel and Gretel). I guess someone started a joke on me at my office, I don't remember having made the change.
So, here's the solution, in case in the future someone happens to have the same problem.

[image: In the filter]

1. Modify the View
2. In the **Filter** section, make sure the "**View all items in this view**" is checked.
3. Hide yourself under your desk/a carpet until everyone left your office. It is allowed to cry.

On this matter, I still have to complete step number 3...

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. I had similar issues with some clients. You should definitely revoke some people's edit rights on lists :)